# How to recover an erased external drive partition?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I have a 2009 iMac running Ventura 13.4.
I was messing with a USB key and accidentally erased my 3TB external media drive using Disk Utility. I originally used Disk Utility to create a single large partion on that external drive.
Here is what Disk Utility shows now.

[image: Media]
[image: Container]

[image: Partition]

Here is the output of diskutil list
[image]
Here is the output of gpt show
[image]
How can I recover all my media files?
I have looked at the man for gpt and diskutil plus read a similar question/answer on apple.stackexchange but I’m uncertain exactly what to do. I don’t want to make a mistake and lose my files.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the command line output as text, not an image.  You can do this by appending `| pbcopy` to the command to redirect the output to your clipboard.  Text contained in images aren’t indexed by search engines and it’s difficult to read/copy.

Comment: Is it actually erased, or just unmounted? I can't see anything in those images that says it shouldn't just mount if told.

Comment: As root, in a terminal window I entered "diskutil mountDisk disk5", and my file system on that external drive appeared. Thanks Tesujin!

Comment: This seems to be a user error then, as "accidentally erased my 3TB external" doesn't actually have happened.

Comment: I erased the partition. The drive did not display in Finder anymore and in Disk Utility the partition appeared greyed out as you can see from my screen grabs. Definitely erased. But thanks for playing nohillside.

Comment: And, @nohillside denied my edit, so no help for people in this situation in the future. Way to pay attention to the details! I’m out.

Comment: The main issue currently is that the question is not really clear. You share a lot of screenshots without explaining what is wrong on them, nor what you have already tried. IMHO the screenshots just show an unmounted disk, so remounting it (as you did) seems to be straightforwarded.

Comment: But we may miss something here. How did you "erase" the partition?

Comment: tbh, I don't think this is now a dupe. Though we don't have the full story, it just seems like user error. Drive was [somehow] simply unmounted rather than erased. All the images just show an unmounted drive. Unless it also managed to get itself listed in fstab, it's now back in action, mounted & ought to continue that way through reboots.

Comment: @Tetsujin Agreed, right now it rather lacks detail. And the third screenshot even shows "not mounted".

Comment: @nohillside i actually, based on what we do have, if you want to reopen it i can put an answer in - unless there really is something deeper that doesn't show up until reboot, I think we have an explanation & 'fix'.

Comment: @Tetsujin It might be one of those questions where an answer helps to clarify the actual problem. Go ahead then.

Comment: @nohillside - there we go… see what you think.

Comment: @nohillside I was trying to erase a USB that was also plugged in to my system. I had the external drive selected and I hit the erase button. I think there was a confirmation I also hit, then my drive apparently was unmounted and not erased. I did not hit the unmount button.

Answer (score 2):

After comments, I think what we actually have here is a misdiagnosis of the initial issue. None of the images posted indicate a drive has been erased, merely unmounted.

Using a similar, if not identical structure on my own Mac, let me try to demonstrate. Let's concentrate on the Samsung drive, bottom of this list…

[image]

In the hierarchy on the left you can see that Kick-Ext is greyed out. This is because it's currently unmounted.

Selecting the Container disk [coincidentally also 7] shows us graphically which volumes are mounted & which are not.

[image]

Going deeper to the actual volume itself we get an indicator in the graphical side of the window, again that states the drive is not mounted.
The images I'm posting are from a slightly older OS, so they're not identical, but the message is the same.

[image]

From here you can re-mount the volume using the Mount button, highlighted in red.

And now the listing on the left un-greys [& adds a small unmount button] & the graphical side of the window now has pertinent information.

[image]

Unless there is a deeper issue, the volume will stay mounted, even through reboots.